# My one url is not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to ask that when i upload .htaccess file to my hostgator server my one of url is not working

url: email/admin/index.php

the htacces code here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.appynator.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^appynator\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.appynator.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(\?|\ )
RewriteRule ^ http://www.appynator.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```